# meaning of &variable (passed to function)

Tags: c, embedded

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    func(&a)
}
```

(func being some arbitrary user defined function)

What is the meaning of this &? i know that its the reference variable, but so far I have only seen it being used in a function definition.

(Also, the variable a in the actual code is probably global or extern or something, I'm not sure :-/ ).

Comment: Prepending a variable with `&` gives the the memory address of that variable. The function `func` is probably expecting an argument of type `int *` or some other pointer type.

Comment: & is not the reference operator (not variable) in C. You are thinking about C++ where it can be used to define references. & is the address of operator - it gives the address of a variable in memory.

Comment: *"so far I have only seen..."* - you should post an example of what you are talking about because it is not clear - someone can then clarify the difference.  The `&` is used for two distince operators in C and is also used as a type qualifier in C++ - context is everything.  That is a function *call* not a *definition*. *reference arguments* where the & is part of a type declaration (e.g. `int& a`) is C++ not C.  This function definition would have the signature `void func( int* )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `func` being some arbitrary user defined function

It couldn't be "arbitrary" - it must take a pointer to `int` or a `void*` in order for the call to be legal.

This ampersand is the "take address" operator. It passes `func` the address of `a`, so that the `func` could, for example, modify it:

```
void func(int *pa) {
    *pa = 4; // Note the asterisk - it "undoes" the effect of the ampersand
}
```

If your `main` prints `a` after the call to `func`, it prints `4` instead of `3`.

Note that if you pass `a` instead of a pointer to `a` to a function that takes an `int`, not an `int*`, then modifications done to that `int` inside the function will have no effect on the parameter that you pass, because in C parameters are passed by value.

> the variable a in the actual code is probably global or extern or something

It is probably not global, because there is no point in passing globals around: by virtue of being global, they are already accessible from everywhere.

Comment: So am i to understand that in c to pass a variable that i want to modify in the function i use `&variable`, and the function input requires a pointer
The equivalent in c++ being that i declare a function as 
`func(int& name)` and simply pass `a` to it in main, rather than `&a`

Comment: @user3660420 Yes, this is correct. In C++ you have a choice of passing by reference (i.e. writing `func(int& a)` functions), which is absent from C. Of course you can use pointers in C++, too.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Im learning c++ while working on an embedded c project at the same time, its a bit of a mess

Comment: Taking a global variable argument is not so far fetched.  You might want to perform the same operation on a number of different globals.  That said - [A Pox on Globals](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals), but the nature of the variable of down to the caller other than being an `int`, so it is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @user3660420 : So why not use C++ in your embedded project?

Comment: @Clifford : Because its not hobby work, and I didn't start it - there's a lot of pre-existing code

Answer (score 3):

the `&` means, that you are passing the address of that variable to the function. 
That is needed when the function takes a pointer argument and you only have an atomic variable.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is used in function call to pass the address of the variable (following `&`) to the function.
Since in C, there is no call by reference, you need to pass the address of the variable to the function if you are interested to reflect the changes to the variable in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The expression  `&<variable>` yields the address of `<variable>`.

In your example it would allow `func()` to directly modify the value of `main()`'s local variable `a`, by dereferencing (e.g. `*a = b`).

In your example, the result might more simply and safely be returned from the function normally: `a = func()` for example), but the technique is more generally useful for:

- Obtaining more than one result from a function through multiple pointer-arguments in addition to or instead of the return value.
- Efficiently passing very large objects to functions (where the argument might be `const` qualified if it is for input only).